# Using "Format as table" to filter rows is slow

Tags: excel, filter, excel-formula

I currently have a sheet that has 1381 rows and 128 columns (info type by rows, country by columns).
Above the data I have several buttons that keeps only specific rows hidden, that belong to a group or section.
I was asked to allow more than one section to remain visible, and what I did is inserted 1 column, filled it with the Section name, used "Format as table" only on that row, created a slicer from that table, and that allows me to use the Slicer to Hide/Unhide rows that have the same Section Name.
The problem is it is very slow if I use it this way, I select a section from the slicer, or filter, and it takes 2-3 minutes to process...
I converted the table to a normal range, generated the filter, and it's almost instant, but I lose slicer functionality if i do it this way.

The only formula I use on the only column converted to table is:

```
=CHOOSE(--SWITCH_REG+1,OffChar,OnChar) & " " & "Site contracting"
```

The "SWITCH_" and the ending string change for each section, but they are manually generated, so I don't see why the table is so slow.

Am I doing something wrong that the table filter is so slow?

Comment: Once you get to a certain threshold in a formatted table, excel will slow down massively, if you have the calculation of the sheet on automatic. You can set it to manual, to speed up the process. As a note: Excel recalculates all cells in your table, once one change is done.

Comment: Do you think using an IF statement instead of the Choose wil speed up the process?

Comment: Or better yet, is there a shape similar to a Slicer that i can use to get the same result by manipulating the filter? I mean i can use buttons, but sometimes they misaligned and some of them grow, so they lose their symmetry. Is there a "Button group" that i can use? If yes, what is it called?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue by following these steps:

1. Converted table to range.
2. Created pivot table with 1 field from said
   range.
3. Created Slicer from the pivot table.
4. Added macro trigger on pivot table change to get filter values from the Slicer and apply them as a filter to the initial range. Code below:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate(ByVal Target As PivotTable)

    Dim rngTableAll As Range, filterField, arrFilterValues
    Dim firstCol, lastCol, sectionI     

    'UPDATE FILTER WHEN SLICER IS UPDATED
    If Target.NAME = "CatPiv" Then
        With Inputs_03
            Set rngTableAll = .Range("_FilterDatabase")
            filterField = 1
            arrFilterValues = GETSLICERITEMS_ARRAY("Slicer_SubCat")
            rngTableAll.AutoFilter Field:=filterField, Criteria1:=arrFilterValues, Operator:=xlFilterValues, VisibleDropDown:=False

            'HIDE ARROWS 'CAREFULL, IT'S SLOW
'            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'            For filterField = 2 To rngTableAll.Columns.Count - 2
'                rngTableAll.AutoFilter Field:=filterField, VisibleDropDown:=False
'            Next
'            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
        End With

    End If

End Sub
Public Function GETSLICERITEMS_ARRAY(SlicerName As String)
    'https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1178647-trigger-event-on-slicer-selection-update.html
    Dim arrItems, strItems

    strItems = GETSLICERITEMS(SlicerName)
    arrItems = Split(strItems, ", ")

    GETSLICERITEMS_ARRAY = arrItems
End Function
```

How to get slicer items: 'https://www.excelforum.com/excel-general/1178647-trigger-event-on-slicer-selection-update.html